# Script to update thousands of SQL records with a unique ID

Tags: sql-server

I've got a table named 'users' with 5800 records where the externalID is NULL. I want to add an unique externalID to each of these records in the following format: 'legacy_N' where N is some number between 1 and 5800.

this:

```
ID     externalID     Name      AddedUTC
123                   John      2019-09-19 15:14:11.837
634                   Susan     2019-09-18 20:39:38.247
499                   Lolita    2019-09-18 19:58:29.320
...
```

becomes this:

```
ID     externalID     Name      AddedUTC
123    legacy_1       John      2019-09-19 15:14:11.837
634    legacy_2       Susan     2019-09-18 20:39:38.247
499    legacy_3       Lolita    2019-09-18 19:58:29.320
...
```

Anyway I can do this programatically? Or am I about to spend the 8 hours updating these one by one?

Comment: Use a `SEQUENCE`. Use a `CURSOR` in a `WHILE` loop. Use `CONCAT` with your existing `IDENTITY` column. Etc.

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER() with a CTE to select the ID ordered by AddedUTC, and then update by joining with the CTE on ID, and using 'legacy_' + CAST(RowNum AS varchar), and you should be good. But yes, you can do this programmatically, and no, you don't need to update one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example based on the data in your question:

```
-- Create a test table with test data in it
CREATE TABLE TestData([ID] int, [externalID] varchar(20), [Name] varchar(50), [AddedUTC] datetime);
INSERT INTO TestData ([ID], [externalID], [Name], [AddedUTC])
VALUES (123, NULL, 'John', '2019-09-19 15:14:11.837'),
       (499, NULL, 'Lolita', '2019-09-18 19:58:29.320'),
       (634, NULL, 'Susan', '2019-09-18 20:39:38.247');

-- Display the test data
SELECT * FROM TestData;

-- Do the update
WITH NumberedData AS (
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AddedUTC) AS RowNum 
      FROM TestData
)
UPDATE td
   SET [externalID] = 'Legacy_' + CAST(RowNum AS varchar)
  FROM TestData td
       INNER JOIN NumberedData nd ON td.ID = nd.ID

-- Display updated data
SELECT * FROM TestData;
```

If you want to order by ID, then you can change the ROW_NUMBER clause to "OVER(ORDER BY ID)" instead.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for detailed explanation.